# Google Map SDK 1.4.3 for iOS 7 Beta Version

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios7, xcode5, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have an app on AppStore in which Google Map SDK 1.4.3 is working fine with InfoWindow for earlier iOS versions, But it is not working in iOS 7 Simulator. This delegate method of GMSMapView is not called and also zoom in and zoom out of map is not working.

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;
```

Is this bug in iOS 7 Beta Version?

Comment: Hi SergiusGee, Thanks for replying i know that iOS 7 is still under NDA but where i need to post a question either in Google Dev Forum or Apple Dev Forum because i dont know from which side it is problem?

Comment: The question about iOS 7 should be posted in the Apple Dev Forums until it goes out of NDA, that's my opinion.